# python joblib returning `TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object` with the same code, but different input data

Tags: python, joblib, music21

I'm trying to parallelise code which converts strings to a third party package object using a function defined in that library. However, `joblib` is failing depending on the input data that I provide. Are the return types of the function important when using joblib?

## To reproduce the issue:

First install third party libraries with:

```sh
pip install joblib music21
```

and download the data file [test_input.abc](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxr8bick0j4vpe4/test_input.abc?dl=0) (it's 4kb of text).

This code will run fine as a script:

```py
from typing import List

import music21
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def convert_string(string: str, format: str = "abc") -> music21.stream.Score:
    return music21.converter.parse(string, format=format)


def convert_list_of_strings(
    string_list,
    n_jobs=-1,
    prefer=None
) -> List[music21.stream.Score]:
    return Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, prefer=prefer)(
        delayed(convert_string)(string) for string in string_list
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    string_list = ['T:tune\nM:3/4\nL:1/8\nK:C\nab cd ef|GA BC DE' for _ in range(1000)]
    output = convert_list_of_strings(string_list)
    print(output)
```

i.e. it returns a list of `music21.stream.Score` objects.

However, if you change the main call to read the attached file, i.e.:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepath = "test_input.abc"
    tune_sep = "\n\n"
    with open(filepath, "r") as file_object:
        string_list = file_object.read().strip().split(tune_sep)
    output = convert_list_of_strings(string_list)
    print(output)
```

This will return the following error:

```
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 356, in _sendback_result
    result_queue.put(_ResultItem(work_id, result=result,
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/queues.py", line 241, in put
    obj = dumps(obj, reducers=self._reducers)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/reduction.py", line 271, in dumps
    dump(obj, buf, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/reduction.py", line 264, in dump
    _LokyPickler(file, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 563, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "joblib_test.py", line 50, in <module>
    output = convert_list_of_strings(string_list)
  File "joblib_test.py", line 39, in convert_list_of_strings
    return Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, prefer=prefer)(
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1054, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 933, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 542, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 444, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
```

## What I've tried to fix

- Checked that the code runs fine when run without parallelism i.e. set `n_jobs=1`
- Changed joblib's backend to use threads i.e. set `prefer="threads" - this fixes things, i.e. it will not error` - but I don't want to use threads!
- Tried serializing the **output** of the function, i.e. changing `convert_string` to:

```py
def convert_string(string: str, format: str = "abc") -> str:
    return music21.converter.freezeStr(music21.converter.parse(string, format=format))
```

this also means the code will run...but now I have thousands of objects I need to deserialize!

- Checked the input data type is all the same when reading from the file, and the first method (i.e. it's a list of strings)
- Checked the output data type is all the same when reading from the file, and the first method (i.e. it's a list of `music21.stream.Score`)
- Faffed about with [@wrap_non_pickleable_objects](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/serialization_and_wrappers.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-serialization-and-wrappers-py)

So I'm guessing that the *content* of the `music21.stream.Score` in the output is causing issue?

Comment: FYI, when I had a peek at your file: it generates a stream.Opus object rather than stream.Score.

Comment: Thanks @JacobWalls - you’re right that it will create an opus if I load it in one go. But I’m not doing that, I’m splitting the file first before loading. I have to do this because, in reality, I have a huge file where some of the tunes cause error upon loading - currently the opus loader will error if one of the individual tunes errors during parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Change `music21.sites.WEAKREF_ACTIVE = False` (you might need to edit music21/sites.py directly) and music21 won't use any weak references.  They'll probably disappear in v8 anyhow (or maybe even sooner since they're mostly an implementation detail).  They were needed for running `music21` in the Pre-Python2.6 circular reference counting era, but they're not really necessary anymore.

However, you're not going to get much of a speedup in your code, because the process of serializing and deserializing the Stream for passing across the multiprocessing worker-core->controller-core boundary will usually take as long as parsing the file itself, if not more.  I can't find where I wrote it at some point but there's a guide to parallel running music21 that suggests do all your stream parsing in the worker-core and only pass back small data structures (counts of numbers of notes, etc.), not the whole score.

Oh, for some of these things, music21's common.parallel library (which uses joblib) will help make common tasks easier:

https://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleCommonParallel.html

Comment: thank you @michael-scott-cuthbert. If at the top of the script, I 
```
print(music21.sites.WEAKREF_ACTIVE)
music21.sites.WEAKREF_ACTIVE = False
print(music21.sites.WEAKREF_ACTIVE)
```
I see that I can change this value, but the error persists. If I change [this line](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/blob/dd46fb1157c8a6052ba0757a307522703fd6cfeb/music21/sites.py#L25) and compile from source, the error still persists (I can tell my change was installed because the first print shows the value `False`).